# Node.js forward proxy to serve a web page

Tags: node.js, proxy

I am trying to set up a forward proxy to serve web pages in nodejs (using the request package).

I can get the web page to be served up, however my problem is in the assets that the webpage tries to reference, they are (of course), all relative pathing (e.g. images/google.png).

my code is thus:

```
... 

app.get('/subdomain/proxy/:webpage', function(req, resp) {
    req.pipe(request('http://' + req.params.webpage)).pipe(resp);
}

...
```

and the response I get, given proxy.mywebsite.com/www.google.com looks like (google inline-styles its css):[image: proxied webpage]

So, the question is:

**How do I load in resources that are relatively pathed? Is my approach here regarding a forward proxy even correct?**

My only solution is to scrape all relative paths and rewrite the html to be absolute references instead which sounds horrific (and doesn't account for cases where the external .js scripts could also relatively reference stuff).

It must be possible as there are websites like 'hidemyass' which achieve the same thing.

This is all **extremely** new to me, but it seems like I'm asking for something quite simple and I'm quite surprised I've not been able to find a solution yet.

Comment: Why are you making a web proxy instead of an http proxy? Second one is way easier to implement.

Comment: I'm not even sure what kind of proxy I'm making, I'll happily implement a http proxy if it will have the same result (which is what I thought I was doing?)